# Vetores nomes e idades - Python

Tags: python

Desejo criar dois vetores, um para nomes e outro para idades, o qual possa armazenar 10 pessoas.

Creio que seria:

```
pessoas = []
idades = []
for c in range(10):
    pessoas.append(input('Digite o nome da pessoa: '))
    idades.append(int(input('Digite agora a idade da pessoa: ')))
```

Porém como eu poderia mostrar agora a pessoa mais nova (de menor idade)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A lógica é bastante simples, porém um pouco trabalhosa. Tendo as duas listas, uma de nomes e outra de idades, segue:

1. Buscar a menor idade na lista de idades;
2. Buscar a posição na lista em que a menor idade se encontra;
3. Verificar na lista de nomes, nessa mesma posição, o nome da pessoa mais nova;

O código seria algo como:

```
menor_idade = min(idades)
posicao_menor_idade = idades.index(menor_idade)
nome = pessoas[posicao_menor_idade]

print(f'{nome} é a pessoa mais nova, com {menor_idade} anos')
```

Essa é uma maneira *crua* de se fazer, o que compromete um pouco a legibilidade do código. Ao meu ver, o ideal não é armazenar duas informações que estão relacionadas entre si em listas diferentes, mas sim em uma estrutura única, tal como uma tupla. Por exemplo:

```
pessoas = []
for _ in range(10):
    nome = input('Digite o nome da pessoa: ')
    idade = int(input('Digite agora a idade da pessoa: '))
    pessoas.append((nome, idade))
```

E buscar pela pessoa mais nova com:

```
pessoa_mais_nova = min(pessoas, key=lambda p: p[1])
```

Tendo assim, um retorno como: `('João', 10)`.

Para melorar ainda mais, você pode utilizar a [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple):

```
Pessoa = namedtuple('Pessoa', ['nome', 'idade'])

pessoas = []
for _ in range(10):
    nome = input('Digite o nome da pessoa: ')
    idade = int(input('Digite agora a idade da pessoa: '))
    pessoas.append(Pessoa(nome, idade))

pessoa = min(pessoas, key=lambda p: p.idade)
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/LightgraySkeletalChords) | [GitHub GIST](https://gist.github.com/289f4755643eb5d34311d2f1178e45dc)</sup>

- [Qual a diferença de namedtuple e NamedTuple?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/305551/5878)

Obtendo o retorno: `Pessoa(nome='João', idade=10)`, podendo exibí-lo:

```
print(f'{pessoa.nome} é a pessoa mais nova, com {pessoa.idade} anos')
```

> A sintaxe do `print()` com o prefixo `f` funciona apenas nas versões 3.6+. Para versões anteriores, use o método `format`.

Na versão 3.7 do Python foi incluindo o padrão *Data Class*, que pode ser utilizado nesta situação, bem semelhante ao que o [LINQ](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/298932/5878) colocou na sua resposta, porém de uma maneira mais simples:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Pessoa:
    nome: str
    idade: int
```

E seguir da mesma forma:

```
pessoas = []
for _ in range(10):
    nome = input('Digite o nome da pessoa: ')
    idade = int(input('Digite agora a idade da pessoa: '))
    pessoas.append(Pessoa(nome, idade))

pessoa = min(pessoas, key=lambda p: p.idade)
```

- [O que são dataclasses e quando utilizá-las?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/376306/5878)

Comment: Não conhecia essa parada do `f` com interpolação. Você é o mestre!

Comment: @LINQ Funciona na 3.6+

Answer (score 6):

O código poderia ser escrito de uma forma um pouco melhor, para evitar alguns problemas, como, por exemplo, quando duas pessoas têm a mesma idade.

Mas, se você não quiser atropelar as coisas e acabar se perdendo nos estudos, segue um exemplo de como poderia ser feito:

```
pessoas = []
idades = []
for c in range(3):
    pessoas.append(input('Digite o nome da pessoa: '))
    idades.append(int(input('Digite agora a idade da pessoa: ')))

menor_idade = min(idades)         # Obtém o menor valor em 'idades'
index = idades.index(menor_idade) # Obtém o index deste valor

print(f'{pessoas[index]} é a pessoa mais nova, com {menor_idade} anos')
```

<sup>[**Veja funcionando no repl.it**](https://repl.it/@jfbueno/AgitatedWarlikeProjections) | [GitHub](https://github.com/jfbueno/Stack-Overflow-Portugues/blob/master/Python/298927/v1.py)</sup>

Esta é uma implementação ingênua que se baseia no fato de que uma pessoa e sua idade sempre serão armazenados no mesmo indíce, uma vez que são inseridas ao mesmo tempo e a inserção é sempre é feita com o par (nome, idade) **completo**.

Uma implementação um pouco menos ingênua, seria usar uma classe para guardar as informações de uma pessoa:

```
class Pessoa:
    def __init__(self, nome, idade):
        self.nome, self.idade, = nome, idade

pessoas = []
for c in range(3):
    nome = input('Digite o nome da pessoa: ')
    idade = int(input('Digite agora a idade da pessoa: '))
    pessoa = Pessoa(nome, idade)
    pessoas.append(pessoa)

pessoa = min(pessoas, key = lambda p: p.idade)

print(f'{pessoa.nome} é a pessoa mais nova, com {pessoa.idade} anos')
```

<sup>[**Veja funcionando no repl.it**](https://repl.it/@jfbueno/CarelessWorldlyDirectory) | [GitHub](https://github.com/jfbueno/Stack-Overflow-Portugues/blob/master/Python/298927/v2.py)</sup>